# Repeated record to one string, BigQuery

Tags: arrays, string, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, record

I have a table that contains query jobs, with a repeated record colomn *referenced_tables*. There are 3 colomns and several rows inside this record, and I would like to transform the whole record into a single string, with a seperator for the colomns '.' and ',' for the rows. The colomns inside the record are project, dataset and table id's (string), and each row is a different table. I am trying something like this :

```
select array_to_string(
    [
        array_to_string(
            [
                referenced_tables[ordinal(1)].project_id, 
                referenced_tables[ordinal(1)].dataset_id, 
                referenced_tables[ordinal(1)].table_id
            ], "."
        ),
        array_to_string(
            [
                referenced_tables[ordinal(2)].project_id, 
                referenced_tables[ordinal(2)].dataset_id, 
                referenced_tables[ordinal(2)].table_id
            ], "."
        )
    ], ", "
)
FROM my_table
```

The result of this is like : *project1.dataset1.table1,project2.dataset2.table2* when i specify a job. So it works but I have to repeat the *array_to_string* as much as there are rows, and of course the number of rows changes from a job to another, and *referenced_tables* can be NULL, so if i do this on the whole table, an error will occur.

Is there a way to transform the records into strings, for the whole table, with my conditions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made some assumptions about how your data is structured.  Given you said this is by query there is some kind of query_id associated to group by.

Try the following

```
select
  string_agg(concat(t.project_id,".",t.dataset_id,".",t.table_id),", ") 
from sample_data
, unnest(referenced_tables) t
```

With the following sample data:

```
with sample_data as (
    select 1 as query_id
        , [STRUCT('my_project' as project_id, 'my_dataset' as dataset_id, 'table' as table_id)
           ,STRUCT('my_project1' as project_id, 'my_datase1' as dataset_id, 'table1' as table_id)
           ,STRUCT('my_projec2' as project_id, 'my_dataset2' as dataset_id, 'table2' as table_id)
           ] as referenced_tables
    UNION ALL 
    select 2
        , [STRUCT('my_project3' as project_id, 'my_dataset3' as dataset_id, 'table3' as table_id)
           ,STRUCT('my_project4' as project_id, 'my_datase4' as dataset_id, 'table4' as table_id)
           ,STRUCT('my_projec5' as project_id, 'my_dataset5' as dataset_id, 'table5' as table_id)
           ] as referenced_tables
)
```

It produces
[image]

Comment: Thank you it works, but not exactly how i'd like. I need the same thing, but without the group by, so i can query my whole table, without having the "sub-table" that is referenced_tables.

Comment: The referenced_table isn't a sub-table, it is the unnesting of a column similar to what is described in your example.  If you provide example data with expected output I can get you a little closer.
I've also expanded the example to exclude the group by.

Comment: Okay thx i'm actually new to all this. My problem is solved thx to your 1st solution, I have been able to adapt it to my usage, and it works perfectly :)